# Как изменять размер видео в элементе VideoView Android

Tags: java, android, videoview

Имеется `RelativeLayout` фиксированной ширины. С сервера загружаются различные видео (у каждого свой ratio). При фиксированной высоте, видео сплющенное.

Что лучше изменять размер высоты `RelativeLayout`, или как-то можно менять размеры самого видео уже в контейнере?

```
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
        mVideoView.start();

    }
});



RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(x, y);  ///// ?????????
mVideoView.setLayoutParams(params);

mVideoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (mVideoView.isPlaying()) {
            mVideoView.pause();
            mPlayButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        } else {
            mVideoView.start();
            mPlayButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Разметка: http://pastebin.com/cdWkEK3S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на экране только видео отображается, можно сделать так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/mVideoView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Если не только видео, тогда можно задать фиксированную высоту, а ширину видео как `wrap_content`.

Comment: Спасибо.Сработало.
Единственное,если на разметке не только одно видео,как можно реализовать ?

Comment: Все зависит от расположения элементов. Можно использовать вес элемента в LinearLayout'e.